# what does the following ipv6 address translate to in ipv4 : http://[0::1]:5001/

Tags: java, networking, server, ipv6, ipv4

I see a server connection in the logs with a 401 for the following server address : http://[0::1]:5001/ Trying to figure out what ip is getting accessed here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, there is no direct translation from IPv6 to IPv4 addresses, as they are not related to each other.

In this specific case, it would be possible to say that `::1` in IPv6 corresponds to `127.0.0.1` in IPv4, as they both are the respective way to address the loopback address. But I'd rather not express it that way.

It's better to just say "This is an access to the web server listening on the local machine on port 5001 using IPv6". In other words, it's just an access to `localhost`.